# Will Cappy tell me if there are purple coins left in an area?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I am searching for the last of the purple regional currency and can't find them. If I enter one of the little bonus areas via pipe or doorway, Cappy will usually (but not every room) hint either that there are more power moons, or that it seems there's nothing else to do here. I've never seen him mention anything about coins though. I have found purple coins in these rooms, but never took note of Cappy's remarks.

In short, does Cappy only hint about Power Moons? Or will he give a separate hint regarding any coins which may be found?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Cappy will explicitly tell you if there are any purple coins left in an area, even if you haven’t collected all the moons yet.**

[image]

If a room still has both Power Moons and Purple Coins to find, Cappy first say if there are any moons, then mention that there are some purple coins as well.

Cappy will only say there is nothing left to do in an area if you have collected every power moon and purple coin.

Also note that Cappy will only say if an area has uncollected items [after you've broken the moon rock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/327021/181240) for the area.